# axios response interceptor not working properly

Tags: reactjs, axios

Im trying to use axios interceptor with refresh token but when my token has expired. My error code within in interceptors.response is not executing. What can i do to fix this issue, i am also getting a status code of 200 which does not make much sense to me.

[image]

Also here is my code

```js
proctedInstance.interceptors.request.use(
    async config => {
        const accesstoken = localStorage.getItem('accesstoken');
        config.headers = {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${accesstoken}`,
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
        
        return config;
    },
    error => {
        Promise.reject(error);
    }
)

proctedInstance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    return response
}, 
function (error) {
    const originalRequest = error.config;
    if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {

        originalRequest._retry = true;
        return axios.post('http://localhost:4000/refresh_token')
            .then(res => {
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    localStorage.setItem('accesstoken', res.data.accesstoken)
                    console.log('my token res.data.accesstoken', res.data.accesstoken);
                    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('accesstoken');
                    return axios(originalRequest);
                }
            })
    }

    return Promise.reject(error);
})



export const onProtected = async () => {
    const results = await (await proctedInstance.post('/protected')).data

    if(results.data === 'This is protected data.'){
        return true;
    } else 
        return false;
}
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: Sounds like your backend is incorrectly responding with a 200 status instead of 401

Comment: i understand that know if fixed my previous issue but now i cant get my cookie to refresh with a new token

Comment: I don't see any use of cookies in your question. Did you mean the value in `localStorage`?

Comment: my server sends a cookie for the refresh_token endpoint but it seem to not be working for some reason

Comment: If you need to pass a cookie for `/refresh_token`, you'll need to use the `withCredentials: true` config

Comment: i tried with this code axios.post('http://localhost:4000/refresh_token', { withCredentials: true }) but im still unable to get req.cookies.refreshtoken to have a token

Comment: The config for `axios.post()` goes in the 3rd argument. See https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config

Comment: i do not follow what you mean

Comment: `axios.post("http://localhost:4000/refresh_token", null, { withCredentials: true })`

Comment: thanks for the help ive set my token for a really short time like 5 seconds it seems to be all working now. ill keep testing it thanks for help Phil

Comment: one question though when i click for the protected route i get the right errors but i have to click the protected route to actually get to the protected page i dont think it is supposed to work like this do have any suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try letting it like this:

```
proctedInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    function (response) {
        return response;
    },
    function (error) {
        const access_token = localStorage.getItem("accesstoken");
        if (error.response.status === 401 && access_token) {
            //Your logic to refresh token and reattempt request
        } else {
            console.error(error);
        }
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);
```